# Airflow codebase is using outdated commit. How do I point it the most recent one?

Tags: github, airflow

For some reason Airflow is not picking up the most recent GitHub commit and is running on an outdated codebase using a commit from 2 days ago.

How can I point it to the most recent one? Up until now it has been picking up the most recent commit automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there was a migration happening that caused Airflow to not pick up the latest commits. Post migration everything returned to normal.